# How to summarize data into table filtering by dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to summarize dax table and filter it by date range 5 month back from last `EffectiveDate`, which is 7/27/2019

**So my dax expression:**

```
TestTable1 = 
VAR LastEffDate = LASTDATE(fact_Premium[EffectiveDate])  // --  7/27/2019
RETURN 
SUMMARIZE(
      FILTER(dim_Date, DATEDIFF(DATEADD(STARTOFMONTH(LastEffDate), -5,MONTH), ENDOFMONTH(LastEffDate), MONTH)),
      dim_Date[Year Month],
       "Premium", [Ttl WP]
       )
```

But for some reason it brings me data for all years in a dataset:

[image]

I also tried:

```
TestTable1 = 
    VAR LastEffDate = LASTDATE(fact_Premium[EffectiveDate])  // --  7/27/2019
RETURN 
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
             dim_Date, 
             DATESBETWEEN(dim_Date[Date],
                 DATE(2019,5,1),               
                 DATE(2019,6,1)
             )
        ),
        dim_Date[Year Month],
        "Premium", [Ttl WP]
    )
```

**But it gives me an error:**

```
A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: what does your filter expression evaluates to?

Comment: Can you provide a *.pbix file with data sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter expression should be using DATESBETWEEN and not the datediff:

```
TestTable1 = 
    VAR LastEffDate = LASTDATE(fact_Premium[EffectiveDate])  // --  7/27/2019
RETURN 
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
             dim_Date, 
             DATESBETWEEN(
                 //expression for start date, 
                 //expression for end date
             )
        ),
        dim_Date[Year Month],
        "Premium", [Ttl WP]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried that as well. It gives me an error:  `A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.`

Comment: This formula is for creating a new table. Did you try creating a table or a measure/column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are still missing aggregating your Premium,

> SUM(Ttl WP)

```
TestTable1 =
VAR LastEffDate =
    LASTDATE ( fact_Premium[EffectiveDate] ) // --  7/27/2019
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            dim_Date,
            DATESBETWEEN ( dim_Date[Date], DATE ( 2019, 5, 1 ), DATE ( 2019, 6, 1 ) )
        ),
        dim_Date[Year Month],
        "Premium", SUM ( [Ttl WP] ) ---- Need to aggregate here
    )
```